# Shortest path while walking x unique nodes

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, dijkstra

I have a graph, where all my nodes have a calculated distance to each other.

Now, I want to start at my startNode, and then find the path with the lowest calculated value, as long as the path has X unique nodes. **Think of it as a map:** We start in Paris, and want to travel 3 cities. I want to find the path with 3 total stops away from Paris, with the lowest calculated value.

I am thinking of implementing a modified Dijkstra's algorithm, which normally would give me the shortest distance to an end destination, and then my end destinations is all X_level_out destinations, which should give me a running time of something like O(nodes^level) .

Does this make any sense?
Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Not much to be said other than - a modified Dijkstra's should work just fine.

Comment: It looks like a simple variation on BFS should do

Comment: "I have a graph, where all my nodes have a calculated distance to each other." - Does that mean your graph is complete (an edge between all pairs of nodes)?

Comment: Eran: How would you do this with a BFS? 
Mbeckish: Ah no, sorry. It's not complete.

Comment: Look into the Floyd-Warshall algorithm

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard You can use BFS to find all nodes that are X levels out. While traversing edges, just keep the minimal distances, kind of like in Dijkstra's algorithm. (Dijkstra itself is a generalization of BFS, but you don't have to go "full Dijkstra" here since the path length, or level, is fixed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a weighted  undirected graph G(V,E), and a set S subset of V find the Minimum-Cost tree that spans the nodes in S. This problem is known in the literature as the Steiner tree problem.
The problem is NP-complete, which means that there is no known *polynomial* algorithm that will find the exact solution of the problem. However, there are algorithms that solve the Steiner problem in exponential time (O(2^N)  or O(2^M)).

The Naive or Shortest Paths algorithm.

```
Find the Shortest path tree from one participant node to the rest of the graph. 
Prune the parts of the tree that do not lead to a participant.
```

Complexity O(N^2),  CR = O(M).

The Greedy or Nearest Participant First  algorithm. (Takahashi, Matsuyama 1980) 
Start from a participant.

```
Find the participant that is closest to the current tree. 
Join the closest participant to the closest part of the tree. 
Repeat until you have connected all nodes.
```

Complexity O(M N^2),  CR = O(1), actually CR  <= 2.

The Kou, Markowsky and Berman algorithm (KMB 1981).

```
1. Find the complete distance graph G' 
  (G' has V' = S , and  for each  pair of nodes (u,v) in VxV there is an edge with weight equal to the weight of the min-cost path between these nodes p_(u,v)  in G) 
2. Find a minimum spanning tree  T' in G' 
3. Translate tree T' to the  graph G: substitute every edge of T', which is an edge  of G' with the corresponding path of G. Let us call T the result of the translation. 
4. Remove any possible cycles from T.
```

Complexity O(M N^2), CR = O(1), actually CR <= 2.